# How data will be saved in database for JSON?

Tags: json

Could anyone please tell me about Javascript object notation data Structure?
Brief idea also welcome

Answer (score 0):

JSON not JASON..

you can save it as plain string as it is something like:

```
{
    "colorsArray":[{
            "red":"#f00",
            "green":"#0f0",
            "blue":"#00f",
            "cyan":"#0ff",
            "magenta":"#f0f",
            "yellow":"#ff0",
            "black":"#000"
        }
    ]
}
```

objects within { }
arrays [ ]

more info on [JSON.org](http://json.org/)